# Add emoji to UTF-8 encoded CSV file using shell

Tags: shell, utf-8, emoji

let's say I have a UTF-8 encoded CSV file with just one line of text that says "Hello World"
Now I want to add a purple heart emoji  at the end of the text by using a shell script, so that it says "Hello World " in the file.

Is this possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: `echo  >> myfile.csv`? If your shell can handle UTF-8, that's the most straightforward way…

Answer (score 0):

If your shell supports utf-8 you can do `echo 'Hello World ' >> myfile.csv` like deceze said.

If not then you could do this:

```
printf 'Hello World \U01F49C' >> myfile.csv
```